# PHP session_id() is empty but session_status() is active

Tags: php

I am running a website using PHP sessions. 99.9% of the time this all works fine, but a few times a day session_id() is set to empty. There is no discernible pattern in the type of pages or the type of visitors that experience these issues.

The strange thing is that `session_id()` returns an empty string but `session_status()` is still set to 2 (`PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`). Does anybody know how this could happen and what kind of problems this could indicate?

From everything I can find in the documentation `session_id()` should only be empty for an inactive session, and `session_status()` should only be 2 if there is a valid session ID.

Comment: Sessions and session data are stored in files. Maybe something is happening to those files at those moments? System garbage clean up of tempfiles or something, causing a session file to be deleted whilst still active?

Comment: Hmm, could this result in this strange pattern of the ID being empty but the state being active? I was suspecting that it might be something about the number of open files, but this is very hard to debug since it's very intermittent. Is there anything I could check that would indicate whether this was the problem or not?

Comment: See if you have garbage collecting daemons running that clean up temp files. See how often they do their thing and how they do their thing. If you know which daemon is responsible you might be able to set a setting to only do it to files that are older than 12h(unless you have a very busy site and can't spare the disk space, but I doubt that in this day and age)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the return value of `session_start()` is `TRUE`.

Make sure you are calling `session_start()` before your script outputs anything to the browser.

Check that Apache has write access to the session path; mine is `/tmp`.